# Unsupported Media Type Error in AJAX-Spring

Tags: json, spring, jquery, spring-json

I am trying to pass POST data from my jsp with jquery-ajax to my Spring-MVC controller function. The data is passed fine and I can print the JSON data when I use a String object to receive the **RequestBody**. *But when I employ a DTO which has a List variable declared with its own objects* the controller returns a '**415 Unsupported Media Type Error**' with the following statement,

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

below given is the DTO class

```
    public class anyClassDTO{
          private String name;
          private List<anyClassDTO> subList = new ArrayList<anyClassDTO>();

              //getters and setters here
   }
```

Now, here is the controller function

```
@RequestMapping(headers ={"Accept=application/json"}, value = "urlFromJsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String addData (HttpServletRequest request,
               @RequestBody List<anyClassDTO> dtoObject,    
               Model model)
{       
    return "{\"value\":\"true\"}";
}
```

Is it not possible for a list of objects to be received from the jsp page to a controller via AJAX?

Here is a set of sample data being passed from the jsp

> [{"name":"module1","subList":[{"name":"chapter1","subList":[{"name":"subchapter1","subList":null}]}]},{"name":"module2","subList":[{"name":"chapter1","subList":[{"name":"subchapter1","subList":null}]}]}]

Comment: That's a weird error for the problem I think you are having. It might help if you give us the Spring version you are using.

Comment: The spring version is 3.1 and Jackson Mapper library is 2.3.0

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you please tell me what is 'that' problem that you think I am having?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your AJAX request sets the request's `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

Spring typically uses a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` to convert the request body when you specify `@RequestBody`. This `HttpMessageConverter`  only supports `application/*+json` type content types, so you have to make sure your request contains it.

Comment: In the AJAX call we are already setting the following
_beforeSend : function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
}_

Comment: @evyavan Edit your post and add your AJAX. I tried it with your code and it works. You don't need an intermediate DTO. You can also set your logger to debug to see where Spring bugs out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we could make it work as it is by adding a little more detail. Instead of receiving the @ResponseBody as a List object I created another DTO which holds a List object of the original DTO. So the second DTO is basically a dummy which receives the data from AJAX as a single object.

Like I have said in the question I have a DTO as follows

```
 public class AnyClassDTO{
      private String name;
      private List<anyClassDTO> subList = new ArrayList<anyClassDTO>();

          //getters and setters here
```

}

I created another DTO which holds a List of the above DTO

```
public class DummyDTO{
      private List<AnyClassDTO> dummyObj;

      //getters and setters here
}
```

Then in the controller I changed the function to

```
@RequestMapping(headers ={"Accept=application/json"}, value = "urlFromJsp", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String addData (HttpServletRequest request,
           @RequestBody DummyDTO dummyDTOObj,    
           Model model)
{       
        return "{\"value\":\"true\"}";
}
```

Earlier if I was sending a list directly from AJAX, now I am sending a stringified litteral with a  variable which holds the whole data.

And it works like a charm!